# jQuery append only the options which are not null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append options which are not null only, but i am getting both of the options appended, why?

**jQuery:**

```
   success: function (data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(obj, function (booking_price, value) {

        if (value.AIRBNB_CONF.length > 0 ) {
            $('.searchable').append("<option value=\"" + value.AIRBNB_CONF + "\">" + value.AIRBNB_CONF + "</option>");
        }
        if (value.DBASE_ID.length > 0 ) {
            $('.searchable').append("<option value=\"" + value.DBASE_ID + "\">" + value.DBASE_ID + "</option>");
        }
    });
},
```

I am trying to append either `value.AIRBNB_CONF` or `value.DBASE_ID` but instead both of them getting appended. it should be like if DBASE_ID 1234 contains AIRBNB_CONF append the AIRBNB_CONF otherwise the DBASE_ID...

Comment: `else if (value.DBASE_ID.length > 0 )`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `else if` in the second case, otherwise it always go through second if

```
success: function(data) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  $.each(obj, function(booking_price, value) {

    if (value.AIRBNB_CONF.length > 0) {
      $('.searchable').append("<option value=\"" + value.AIRBNB_CONF + "\">" + value.AIRBNB_CONF + "</option>");
    }
    else if (value.DBASE_ID.length > 0) {
      $('.searchable').append("<option value=\"" + value.DBASE_ID + "\">" + value.DBASE_ID + "</option>");
    }
  });
}
```

For better understanding of `if...else` read the documentation of **[`if...else` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)**

Comment: Thanks! how about using a switch statment?